# mongodb db not found but working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I setup my boliterplate and wanted to start developing with node. The app run well, it already has the register & login part done. But when I do shows db, I didn't see any related database, I only see local.

Comment: Your database is automatically created when you try to insert data in it. It should appear when you create an insert query.

Comment: @ThomasBormans so it's invisible?

Comment: No :) Your database does not exists until it has data. When you insert data in your DB with Node.js, MongoDB will automatically create your database.

Comment: so where does the data been stored when I create a username and password?

Comment: You are creating a MongoDB connection, right? And inside your connection, you have a database name, correct?

Comment: yes, it is `local` and it has only system_index collection inside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95122/discussion-between-thomasbormans-and-nichole-a-miler).